# Integrity constraint violation on setup:upgrade Magento 2.3.3

Tags: setup-upgrade, magento2.3.3

After updating to 2.3.3. I get the following error for the **`Temando_Shipping`** module. I disabled the module but that gives errors when editing products. When I try to enable and run '**`magento setup:upgrade`**' again get this error.

```
Upgrading data.. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'origin.address.countryCode' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `temando_product_attribute_mapping` (`node_path_id`,`label`,`description`,`mapping_attribute_id`,`is_default`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: can you share your script?

Comment: script? There isn't any script. Just did an update to 2.3.3. and then run magento setup:upgrade'. Also after disabling and enabling I get the same error on the "Upgrading data" step.

Comment: @AntondeG May i know how you solve this issue, help me thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318439/57334

Comment: @zus, I used the accepted answer below. That worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `temando/module-shipping-m2` which is required by `magento/product-community-edition`. The data is added in `vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Setup/UpgradeData.php:73`

I first checked if there are any differences between the content in my db and the data the module upgrade step tries to insert:

```sql
select * from temando_product_attribute_mapping;
```

In my case, the data was identical, so I deleted it with

```sql
delete from temando_product_attribute_mapping;
```

and ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade` again. This time, it worked without issues.

Still, this is more a workaround than a solution. I've sent the author of the package a mail to inform him of the problem.

Comment: This indeed works, thx!

Comment: @AntondeG Please accept the anwser if it was helpful for you :)

Comment: perfect solution @kolaente Thank You !!