# Magento 2.3 migration - How to solve Duplicate entry error after data migration?

Tags: theme, migration, magento2.3.4

**Note:** I did data migration couple of times, during data migration max_allowd_packet issue then update and again run the data migration.

How to solve the **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** error,  If i try to run upgrade command i am getting following error,

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
> entry  '21' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
> `eav_attribute_set`  (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`,
> `sort_order`,  `attribute_set_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Queries :

1. [SELECT * FROM  eav_attribute_set WHERE attribute_set_id = '21';](https://snipboard.io/1xrEnz.jpg)
2. [SELECT * FROM eav_attribute_group WHERE attribute_set_id = '21';](https://snipboard.io/qQVaDP.jpg)

**Table : eav_attribute_set**

[image]

What value should i delete?